# Is the set of primitive recursive functions (on $\mathbb{N}$) effectively enumerable?

Tags: computational-complexity, computability, recursion, incompleteness

My intuition says that the set of PR functions on $\mathbb{N}$ are *not* effectively enumerable. I'm trying to come up with a diagonal argument to show this.

Suppose that $f_1,f_2,...$ was an enumeration of all PR functions. Of course, I'd like to show that there is some $g$ which is not on the list. My problem is trying to make sure that $g$ is not on the list, while still making sure $g$ is PR. Would it be possible to say that

\begin{equation}
    g(n) := \sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^n f_j(i)
\end{equation}

I believe that this would make $g$ primitive recursive and different from all of the $f$'s on the list. (The double sum might be overkill...)

**Questions**

1. Is this approach correct?
2. If not, can someone give me a hint or advice?

Comment: What do you mean by "effectively enumerable"?

Comment: Your argument (it it worked) would prove that the set of PR functions is not countable, not that it is not "effectively enumerable", whatever this may mean. Since the set of PR functions is obviously countable (as PR functions are described by finite expressions in a certain language) the argument has to break. (It breaks in that your g is not PR)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea shows that **the primitive recursive functions are not *primitive recursively* enumerable**, in the sense that there is no p.r. function $h$ of two variables such that for every p.r. function $f$ of one variable, for some $n$ we have $$f(x)=h(n, x)$$ for all $x$. The proof is as you've indicated: if such an $h$ existed, then we could build a p.r. function dominating every p.r. function, which is clearly a contradiction.

However, you're claiming something much stronger! The issue is that the argument above crucially uses the assumption that the "enumerator" $h$ is *primitive recursive*, not just *recursive*. If all we know is that $h$ is recursive, then there is no reason to believe that the $g$ we build will be primitive recursive, only that it will be recursive. And if $g$ isn't necessarily primitive recursive, we don't get a contradiction from the fact that $g$ isn't one of the $f_i$s! Indeed, the primitive recursive functions **are** effectively enumerable, in the sense that there is a total recursive function $j$ of two variables such that for each primitive recursive function $f$ of one variable there is some $n$ with $$f(x)=j(n, x)$$ for all $x$.

*Incidentally, this is **not** trivial to prove. What you need to do is show that there is a way to give every p.r. function a "code," so that $(i)$ we can uniformly recursively compute the value of a p.r. function on a given input from that input and a code for the p.r. function, and $(ii)$ the set of codes for p.r. functions is recursive. From $(i)$ and $(ii)$ we can produce a total recursive $j$ enumerating the p.r. functions in the above sense: let $j(n, x)$ be the value of the p.r. function corresponding to the $n$th p.r. code, on input $x$. Rigorously proving $(i)$ and $(ii)$ requires some work.*

---

Going beyond this specific question, the general theme is:

> Suppose $\Gamma$ is a "reasonable" class of total recursive functions. Then there is no $\Gamma$-enumeration of the functions in $\Gamma$.

For example, there is no recursive enumeration of the total recursive functions. Note that "total" here is crucial: we *can* recursively enumerate the *partial* recursive functions, in the sense that there is a partial recursive function $u$ of two variables such that for every partial recursive function $f$ of one variable, for some $n$ we have $$f(x)\cong u(n, x)$$ (where "$a\cong b$" means "either $a$ and $b$ are each undefined, or are each defined and equal). It's a good exercise to think about why we *can't* use diagonalization to derive a contradiction from this (and incidentally this failed diagonalization attempt will ultimately lead to the [**recursion theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_recursion_theorem)).

Comment: But his argument is that his g *is* PR...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez The OP does not in fact make an argument for the p.r.-ness of $g$ - they just say that they believe the function they describe is p.r. The point of my answer is to explain why that is unfounded.

Comment: I find your reading of what the OP wrote very strange :-|

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez The OP asks whether the p.r. functions can be effectively enumerated. Their intuition that the answer is "no" comes from thinking that their function $g$ diagonalizing against a purported recursive enumeration of the p.r. functions will be p.r., and this is of course the flaw. Where I'm making an inference is in assuming that they meant to say that their enumeration $(f_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ should be effective, but this is a reasonable inference in my opinion; I don't think this is a strange reading at all.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez: Could you point more precisely to what in this answer you're disagreeing with? I can't see any contradiction between what you and Noah are saying.

Comment: Certainly the OP doesn't at any point give an argument for the p.r.-ness of their $g$; that is simply something they believe. So I really don't think I'm missing anything here.

Comment: @noah, indeed, what I read differently is that I don't think he thought of his sequence effective: that's why I think that his argument (were the function g PR) is a proof that the set of PR is not countable — this is subtly but in this context significantly different. It is a bit byzantine to try to pinpoint why exactly the post is wrong, bit it is useful in helping the poster :-)